# Insert the result of a PostgreSQL "select" at the end of every line of a file

Tags: linux, postgresql, awk, sed

I have a file with some IPs in the second column

```
[postgres@hotname]$ cat /tmp/ips.txt
538954 10.20.30.1
130708 10.20.30.2  
55300 10.20.30.3
47634 10.20.30.4
```

And a table with the name of the servers along with its IP address.
If I have the name of each IP with this:

```
[postgres@hotname]$ awk '{system("psql database -tc \"select b.des_servidor from cat_servidores a,ctl_servidores b where a.num_ip=\47"$2"\47 and a.idu_servidor = b.idu_servidor\"")}' /tmp/ips.txt
TestServer1
TestServer2
TestServer3
TestServer4
```

How I can insert the name of the server at the end of the file with the IPs, and have something like this:

```
[postgres@hotname]$ cat /tmp/ips.txt
538954 10.20.30.1 TestServer1
130708 10.20.30.2 TestServer2
55300 10.20.30.3 TestServer3
47634 10.20.30.4 TestServer4
```

I've been unsuccessfully trying using awk and sed, but I read somewhere that it is not recommended.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What did you try? Please paste your code... and where did you read that it's not recommended? What exactly is not recommended?

Comment: use `paste file1 file2` if you want to join two files column wise

Comment: Or [`join` utility](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/join-invocation.html#join-invocation)

Comment: I was hoping to get the result doing some adaptation to the line:

`[postgres@hostname]$ awk '{system("psql database -tc \"select b.des_servidor from cat_servidores a,ctl_servidores b where a.num_ip=\47"$2"\47 and a.idu_servidor = b.idu_servidor\"")}' /tmp/ips.txt`

having the base file (/tmp/ips.txt) with the initial information (number column, ip column).

Comment: There is one issue I didn't noticed with the result of the select, because of the trailing blank line after every read the select do.
If I send the result of the command above to a file and later use paste o join:

`[postgres@hostname]$ paste ips.txt names.txt > ips_full.txt`

Comment: The names of the server will not match because for each result of the select, it prints a blank line, so it will results something like this:

`[postgres@hostname]$ paste ips.txt names.txt > ips_full.txt

`[postgres@hotname]$ cat /tmp/ips_ful.txt
538954 10.20.30.1 Server1
130708 10.20.30.2  
55300 10.20.30.3  Server2
47634 10.20.30.4
                  Server3`

Comment: awks NF helps becuase erase all the blank lines,

`[postgres@hostname]$ awk '{system("psql serviciosdbas -tc \"select b.des_servidor from cat_servidores a,ctl_servidores b where a.num_ip=\47"$2"\47 and a.idu_servidor = b.idu_servidor limit 1\" | awk 'NF'") }' regcul_ips.txt > names.txt
 [postgres@hostname]$ paste ips.txt names.txt > ips_full.txt
 [postgres@hostname]$ cat /tmp/ips_ful.txt
538954 10.20.30.1 Server1
130708 10.20.30.2 Server2 
55300 10.20.30.3  Server3
47634 10.20.30.4`

Comment: But the tricky part is that not all the ips are register, so some of them has to be blank. The expected correct result is:

`[postgres@hostname]$ cat /tmp/ips_ful.txt
538954 10.20.30.1 Server1
130708 10.20.30.2 Server2 
55300 10.20.30.3  
47634 10.20.30.4  Server3`

Comment: Because 10.20.30.3, has no register in the table.

I supose that all that i need now is a way to get rid of the trailing blank line when I do the select and have a result.
**I apologize for the loooong explanation. I tried to keep it short, but I couln't.  :-S **

Answer (score 0):

with 'e' flag in `sed`

```
sed -r 's/([^ ]* )(.*)/echo -n \0" " \;psql database -tc "select b.des_servidor from cat_servidores a,ctl_servidores b where a.num_ip=\\47\2\\47 and a.idu_servidor = b.idu_servidor"/e' /tmp/ips.txt
```